# Trying to update NPM in Docker: code EISDIR

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, build

I'm trying to update NPM with `["npm","install","-g","npm"]` but it says:

```
Step 4/12 : RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "npm"]
 ---> Running in 708a95e71771
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! syscall copyfile
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, copyfile '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-31T13_38_29_907Z-debug.log
The command 'npm install -g npm' returned a non-zero code: 235
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /root

COPY package*.json ./
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "npm"]
RUN ["npm", "audit", "fix"]
RUN ["npm", "install"]

COPY ./*.js ./
COPY static ./static
COPY views ./views

COPY conf.d/* /etc/dashboard/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

So it looks like /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI or /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm is a directory and not a file but I think it should be a directory.

On my system (Linux 5.10.2-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux) it works but on my server (Linux 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) it doesn't.

Comment: npm should be a directory where is the copypart where you copy it from your machine to your container?

Comment: I don't copy it. `npm -g install npm` tries to copy something inside the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
From node
```

installs latest node , which has npm version 7+ . Its not stable has some issues

use

```
FROM node:lts
```